# ANTLR - emitting multiple tokens for a lexer rule

Tags: javascript, antlr, lexer

I wanted to know if ANTLR supports emitting multiple tokens for a lexer rule, given the target language is JavaScript. I have found that it supports multiple tokens in other target languages, such as Java and CSharp, but could not find any documentation on this feature being supported in JavaScript.

If anyone could point me to any material on this , that would be great.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Given that the Javascript code generation target is [listed as 'in sync'](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets) with ANTLR3 development I'd assume it would be supported.

The list of [Unsupported Features](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3JavaScriptTarget#ANTLR3JavaScriptTarget-UnsupportedFeatures) also doesn't include this, which is another good sign.  However the Javascript target is listed as beta, so you'll have to build ANTLR from source and try it to know for sure.